# Using preg_replace without destroying id information

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to hack about some sidebar code in a Wordpress template I'm developing. Basically I've captured what I need in an output buffer and I'm running regex over it to replace bits with the code I need. Problem is my regex knowledge is just a bit short on what I need to achieve.

The problem I'm having is as such:

```
$output = preg_replace('/<\/li><li id=".*?" class="widget-container/', '<a href="top">Top</a></li><li><li id="[item from that find]" class="widget-container/', $input);
```

At the moment as the code stands I can find what I need but it destroys those id attributes as I can't capture them.

I'm sure there is a way I can do this to capture and use it in the replacement but I can't find anything that tells me what I need or if I'm taking the wrong approach with preg_replace.

How can I use this to change code without destroying those unique ids?

Cheers guys!

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Interesting read and makes sense. Shall look into using an HTML parser like PHPquery in the near future to replace the dirty regex method I'm using. Thanks for bringing the article to my attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a back reference. Capture the id using ( ) and then reference the capture with $1 ... see below:

```
$output = preg_replace('/<\/li><li id="(.*?)" class="widget-container/', '<a href="top">Top</a></li><li><li id="$1" class="widget-container/', $input);
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend the more precise id="([^"]+)" for clarity.

Comment: Cheers, that did the trick. I thought it was along the lines of $1 but couldn't remember clearly. And to be honest I'd no idea that brackets were for that, I assumed it was for math style grouping.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the pattern you want to match in ( ) and use $1

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/<\/li><li id="(.*?)" class="widget-container/';
$replace = '<a href="top">Top</a></li><li><li id="$1" class="widget-container/'
$output = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $input);
```